# Bright cove video got "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources" error on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I am using bright cove video. Everything is fine on desktop, but this error happened for any mobile device.

Here are the detail:

```
setContent  @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:415
loadError   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:633
showErrorMessage    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:461
handleContentError  @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:430
onMediaError    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:427
dispatchEvent   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:9
redispatch  @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:9
dispatchEvent   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:9
errorHandler    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:374
g   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:2
dispatch    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:2
i   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:2
Promise (async)     
setContent  @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:415
loadError   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:633
showErrorMessage    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:461
handleContentError  @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:430
onMediaError    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:427
dispatchEvent   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:9
redispatch  @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:9
dispatchEvent   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:9
errorHandler    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:374
g   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:2
dispatch    @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:2
i   @   VM404 BrightcovePlayer_api.js:2
```

Here is the code I create for video object, it will create 'object' HTMLElement on desktop, but ifream on mobile.

```
_createPlayerObject: function() {
  var $playerObject = $('<object>', {
    'class': 'BrightcoveExperience'
  });

  var $params = $.map(this.settings, function(value, key) {
    return $('<param>', {
      name: key,
      value: value
    });
  });
  $params.push($('<param>', {
    name: 'templateLoadHandler',
    value: this._createBrightcoveCallback(function(experienceID) {
      this.player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
      this.playerModule = this.player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
      this.experienceModule = this.player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
      this.$el.trigger('playerLoaded.' + unifiedVideoInterface);
    })
  }));
  $params.push($('<param>', {
    name: 'templateReadyHandler',
    value: this._createBrightcoveCallback(function() {
      this.$el.trigger('playerReady.' + unifiedVideoInterface);
      this.bindTriggers();
    })
  }));
  $playerObject.append($params);
  return $playerObject;
},
```

Comment: why do you do something different on mobile ?

Comment: You are using code for Brightcove's legacy player which will be retired at the end of 2017. You should talk to your Brightcove Account Manager or Brightcove Support about your implementation.